# What LaTeX Lab packages use expl3?

Tags: packages, siunitx, expl3, xfrac

I am trying to migrate documents to http://latexlab.org, but they won't compile because they require expl3.sty. Yesterday I started by uploading all of the expl3 sty files but then latex demanded even more.

I would be happy to do without [expl3](https://tug.org/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/), but I can't determine what packages are calling it.

*note: While writing this message, I realized that the xfrac package (see [siunitx](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/exptl/siunitx/)) was the culprit.*

Comment: I'd answer my own question in such a case.

Comment: Same here: there is nothing wrong with asking a question and answering it yourself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a discussion of that on the LaTeX-L mailing list recently. A script was provided there to find all packages with direct or indirect dependency on `expl3`.

Bundles: `expl3`, `xpackages`, `gmutils`, and the following packages:

```
./gmverb/gmverb.sty
./notes2bib/notes2bib.sty
./unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
./libertine/libertine.sty
./randomwalk/randomwalk.sty
./libertine/libertinekey.sty
./tucv/tucv.sty
./xltxtra/xltxtra.sty
./libertine/libertinelist.sty
./metalogo/metalogo.sty
./gmdoc/gmdoc.sty
./siunitx/siunitx.sty
./libertine/libertinelogo.sty
./realscripts/realscripts.sty
./circuitikz/circuitikz.sty
./chemstyle/chemstyle.sty
./fontspec/fontspec.sty
./mh/xfrac.sty
./mh/flexisym.sty
./gmdoc-enhance/gmdoc-enhance.sty
./mh/breqn.sty
./libertine/libertinecomp.sty
```

Search for messages from ~Feb. 25, 2011 on the [latex3 mailing list](http://news.gmane.org/group/gmane.comp.tex.latex.latex3).

Comment: That link goes to a login page.

Comment: @Caramdir: thank you. I fixed it by putting the list explicitly (that's better anyways).

Comment: Easier access is _via_ http://news.gmane.org/group/gmane.comp.tex.latex.latex3

Comment: @Joseph: thank you for the corrected link. I made my answer CW, because it does not seem fair to get more rep' from someone else's script.

Comment: It's fair since it was you who _found_ the appropriate script.

Comment: Link is broken due to gmane.org.  Not sure what to replace it by: any suggestion welcome.

Answer (score 5):

By individually commenting out packages and recompiling, I found that the xfrac package (see [siunitx](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/exptl/siunitx/)) was the culprit.

Comment: The name of the package is `xfrac` (it only defines the `\sfrac` command).

Comment: thanks for the tip, but it says I have to wait until tomorrow

Comment: My question is more general than the answer that I provide; e.g. it is still not clear to me how I can tell, generally, which packages depend on expl3. I would change the selected answer to one that answers this.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a small `texdoc expl3` will tell you that this package introduces syntax for LaTeX3 programming.